Edit Image button disappears when I make WordPress use Imagick instead of GD
Resizing images in WordPress Media -> Library was causing images to lose quality so after searching I found a solution to make it use Imagick instead of GD, I added following code
functions.php
add_filter('wp_image_editors', 'sm_force_imagick');
  function sm_force_imagick() {
    return array('WP_Image_Editor_Imagick');
}

It breaks the image edit page as Edit Image button disappears.
How to fix it?

Are you sure IMagick is installed and enabled on your site's host?

The issue likely arises because forcing only Imagick (WP_Image_Editor_Imagick) as the image editor can conflict with some functionalities, such as the "Edit Image" button in WordPress. This feature may rely on the presence of the default image editor (GD) for certain operations. To fix this, you can modify your code to allow WordPress to use Imagick as the primary option but fall back to GD if necessary. Here's how:

Updated Code
Modify your code in functions.php as follows:
add_filter('wp_image_editors', 'sm_prefer_imagick');
function sm_prefer_imagick($editors) {
    // Ensure Imagick is prioritized but fallback to GD if Imagick is unavailable
    return array('WP_Image_Editor_Imagick', 'WP_Image_Editor_GD');
}


Explanation:

Prioritize Imagick:

The code sets WP_Image_Editor_Imagick as the first option in the array, so WordPress will attempt to use Imagick for image processing.


Fallback to GD:

By including WP_Image_Editor_GD as a secondary option, WordPress will revert to the GD library if Imagick is unavailable or if a feature like the "Edit Image" button relies on it.


Edit Image Compatibility:

Allowing both editors ensures that the "Edit Image" button and other features dependent on GD will work without breaking.




Debugging Steps
If the issue persists, check the following:

Imagick Installation:

Ensure the Imagick PHP extension is installed and enabled on your server. You can verify this by checking the output of phpinfo() or contacting your hosting provider.


Error Logs:

Check the WordPress debug log for errors related to Imagick or image editing. Enable debugging by adding the following lines to wp-config.php:



define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
 Look for logs in `wp-content/debug.log`.


Plugin/Theme Conflicts:

Disable other plugins and switch to a default theme (like Twenty Twenty-Two) to ensure no conflicts are causing the issue.




This updated implementation should resolve the issue with the "Edit Image" button disappearing while still leveraging the better image quality offered by Imagick. Let me know if further troubleshooting is required!

Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Yes it seems to work fine so far. I'm not seeing the log file wp-content/debug.log. Is it normal that WP doesn't create a log file if there is nothing to log?
